# XCode: Looking for Tween & Morph Object solutions

Tags: xcode, flash, flash-cs6, tween

I'm currently developing an iPhone app with Xcode. Part of the app requires the morph (or tween) of one shape into another shape. I know that using Adobe Flash Pro CS6 I can export a 'shape tween' to an iOS app using the built in AIR. The problem is that it does not give me any Objective C code that I can use, just a compiled app. That app cannot be inserted into my development, or have items parsed into it.

The Mac app 'FlashCode', converts SWF into Xcode code, but doesn't yet support shape tweens.

Any ideas how to deal with this?